# need help for select function in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In a table I have 914 rows in that I have a Column which contains "yes or no" values(Yes=193 No = 721 total 914).

In this I want to create a function to use in select statement How many Yes and No

I wrote a query

```
 create function TSS(
@string as nvarchar(20)
)
returns int
begin
  declare @result int
  if (@string='NO')
  select @result=sum(case Re_engaged when 'NO' then 1 else null end) from  TVS_PRE
  else if (@string='YES')
  select @result=sum(case Re_engaged when 'YES' then 1 else null end) from  TVS_PRE
return @result
end

select [dbo].[TSS]('Yes') as columns_with_Yes,[dbo].[TSS]('No') as columns_with_No from  TVS_PRE
```

And I got the result is

| Columns_with_Yes | Columns_with_No |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 193 |
| 2 | 193 |
| 3 | 193 |
| **upto...** | ... |
| 914 | 193 |

but I required this

| Columns_with_Yes | Columns_with_No |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 193 |

Comment: Add a `WHERE`? Use a `MIN`? Though that multi-line scalar function is going to be far from performant; you would be way better off turning it into an inline table value function.

Comment: Better off NOT creating and using a function for such trivial logic that can easily be accommodated in tsql. And your "test" query passes a constant to the function, so of course it returns the same value for every row. Until you have sufficient experience the best approach is to avoid scalar functions.

Answer (score 0):

You should combine this into one query

```sql
SELECT
    sum(case Re_engaged when 'NO' then 1 end) Columns_with_No,
    sum(case Re_engaged when 'YES' then 1 end) Columns_with_Yes
FROM TVS_PRE;
```

If you really want this as a function, you can turn it into an inline Table valued Function

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION TSS()
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN (
    SELECT
        sum(case Re_engaged when 'NO' then 1 end) Columns_with_No,
        sum(case Re_engaged when 'YES' then 1 end) Columns_with_Yes
    FROM TVS_PRE
);

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your need... but if you want only one row... then dont use "from":

```
select [dbo].[TSS]('Yes') as columns_with_Yes,[dbo].[TSS]('No') as columns_with_No
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(CASE WHEN Re_engaged='No' then 1 else NULL end) OVER () AS No_col,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Re_engaged='Yes' then 1 else NULL end) OVER () AS Yes_col
  FROM TVS_PRE
```